# How to automate UI interaction during acceptance test run

Tags: wpf, automated-tests

Scenario 1:

**Given** main window (a window with only 1 button "Execute")
 **When** click "Execute"
 **Then** main window display "Hello, World"

Scenario 2:

**Given** main window (a window with only 1 button "Execute")
 **When** click "Execute" (it will call domainFunc.Execute method, and inside the method it will pop up a messageBox. DomainFunc locates in BL)
  **And** click "Yes" button (the domainFunc.Execute will proceed to next statement)
 **Then** main window display "Hello, World"

I know how to write an automate test for scenario 1, but have no idea for scenario 2. The difficult part of scenario 2 is that I don't know how to gain control of the messageBox to automate its clicking event and proceed the test.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: You don't. You are meant to use MVVM so you don't have to test your view. You test the ViewModel.

Comment: MVVM is not a solution for avoid UI testing. It is a nice way to separate your code to some well defined components, and test it independently. But U have to check your bindings, styles, and UI interactions too. BTW this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480596/how-do-i-get-access-to-a-messagebox-through-wpf-automation-api