# Identify type of MessageBox window shown by Winform app using .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core, ui-automation, ui-testing, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm working on a *.NET core worker service* application that would monitor few *winforms* applications.
These *winforms* applications rarely need any human intervention and the only times they need that is when they show some child window dialogs which are demonstrated below. The goal is to eliminate these rare human interactions using this .NET core worker service.

| App | Main App Window |
| --- | --- |
| someApp.exe | [image] |

| Child Window | Child Window Example Image | Action that I need to take |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Information Window | [image] | Action 1: I just need to click that Ok button and get on with my life. I'll be doing this programmatically. |
| Error Window | [image] | Action 2: I need to restart `someApp.exe`. Again, I'll be doing this programmatically. |

Now I can grab the main window and the subsequent child windows like this:

```
var process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == "someApp");
// Get the main window of the process we're interested in:
AutomationElement appMainWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
// Now the child windows:
var childElements = appMainWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window));
if (childElements.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (AutomationElement childElement in childElements)
    {
        //How do I check if this childElement is an information window or an error window so that I can take my appropriate action?
    }
}
```

What I have done so far:

```
var controlType = childElement.Current.ControlType.LocalizedControlType;
```

This is not helpful because it says *window* for both of the cases.

So my question is:

How do I check if this `childElement` is information MessageBox or error MessageBox so that I can take my appropriate action?

Thank You!

Comment: There is no difference between the two MessageBox types. The only thing is that when they're created, a different system icon is being requested, and that information is not available outside the code that creates the MessageBox. They're both the exact same type of MessageBox.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for your response. In that case, do you have any suggestion on how I would be able to differentiate between the two MessageBoxes? Is reading the error/ message text the only option?

Comment: I'm not even sure you can do that - it would depend on exactly how Windows creates the dialog itself. My suggestion would be to contact whoever wrote someApp.exe and get them to give you the option to turn off the deprecation message, and for them to fix whatever is causing the runtime error that requires you to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see windows UIA elements structure and properties using tools like [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf), [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/testing-tools), [UIA Verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/ui-automation-verify), UISpy, and do checks based on found differences.